# How to avoid repetitions / use constants in Facelets page?

Tags: jsf-2, constants, facelets, dry

In a Facelets page, I have various `<h:inputText>` and `<h:outputText>` components, which all need the same converter.

I'd like to avoid repeating the converter with all its parameters, like this:

```
<h:inputText id="bla" value="#{mybean.val}" >
  <f:convertNumber locale="en" maxFractionDigits="3" minFractionDigits="3"/>
</h:inputText>
[...]
<h:outputText id="bla2" value="#{mybean.val2}" >
  <f:convertNumber locale="en" maxFractionDigits="3" minFractionDigits="3"/>
</h:outputText>
[...]
<h:inputText id="bla3" value="#{mybean.val3}" >
  <f:convertNumber locale="en" maxFractionDigits="3" minFractionDigits="3"/>
</h:inputText>
```

What is the best way to avoid these repetitions?

I think I could use `<ui:include>`, but that would mean I'd have to have a separate file just for a single line, which seems a bit silly. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subclass the converter whereby you set the defaults in the constructor.

```
@FacesConverter("defaultNumberConverter")
public class DefaultNumberConverter extends NumberConverter {

    public DefaultNumberConverter() {
        setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        setMinFractionDigits(3);
        setMaxFractionDigits(3);
    }

}
```

And use it as follows:

```
<h:inputText id="bla" value="#{mybean.val}" converter="defaultNumberConverter" />
[...]
<h:outputText id="bla2" value="#{mybean.val2}" converter="defaultNumberConverter" />
[...]
<h:inputText id="bla3" value="#{mybean.val3}" converter="defaultNumberConverter" />
```

To get a step further, [create a tag file or perhaps a composite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen/6822269#6822269) wrapping the desired components:

```
<my:inputNumber id="bla" value="#{mybean.val}" />
[...]
<my:outputNumber id="bla2" value="#{mybean.val2}" />
[...]
<my:inputNumber id="bla3" value="#{mybean.val3}" />
```

Comment: In your first approach (subclassing the converter), where would this class be located in a typical JSF2.3 project hierarchy?

Comment: `com.example.view.converter`? We don't really care as long as it's clear to *you* :)

Comment: `com.example.view.converter` seems great, and I just found out it's the same path you used in OmniFaces's kickstart project. This is my first time using JSF / Primefaces / etc, and your blog (and OmniFaces) are absolutely **AMAZING**! I just _had_ to thank you eventually ;-)