# Composite Component with f:convertNumber won't work

Tags: jsf, converters, composite-component

I made a JSF composite component which uses `f:convertNumber`. However, it cannot convert value. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

currency.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:composite="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <composite:interface>
    </composite:interface>

    <composite:implementation>
        <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###" currencyCode="\\"/> 
    </composite:implementation>
</html>
```

index.xhtml

```
...

<h:outputText value="10000000">
  <mycomp:currency />
</h:outputText>

...
```

result

```
10000000
```

Comment: 'Cannot convert' is to vague. Care to more explicitly describe the problem AND whad actually does happen?

Comment: @Kukeltje Thanks, I expected that my Composit Componet(currency.xhtml) converted h:outputText's value to "10,000,000" as pattern attribute(#,###).
However, it displayed "10000000". Therefore, I think the converter cannot convert the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will indeed not work.

Composite components are interpreted as UI components. The `<f:convertNumber>`, however, is a taghandler, not an UI component. Basically, it will get applied on the composite itself (and render as useless), not on the target component as you intented.

You've at least two options:

1. Move `<h:outputText>` into the composite too,

   ```
   <composite:interface>
       <composite:attribute name="value" />
   </composite:interface>
   <composite:implementation>
       <h:outputText value="#{cc.attrs.value}">
           <f:convertNumber pattern="#,###" currencyCode="\\" />
       </h:outputText>
   </composite:implementation>
   ```

   so you can ultimately use it as below.

   ```
   <mycomp:currency value="10000000" />
   ```
2. Subclass [`NumberConverter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/convert/NumberConverter.html) with default values set in constructor and use it instead.

   ```
   @FacesConverter("defaultCurrencyConverter")
   public class DefaultCurrencyConverter extends NumberConverter {

       public DefaultCurrencyConverter() {
           setPattern("#,###");
           setCurrencyCode("\\");
       }

   }
   ```

   ```
   <h:outputText value="10000000" converter="defaultCurrencyConverter" />
   ```

   When you register this converter in a tagfile as described here [Creating custom tag for Converter with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31406474/creating-custom-tag-for-converter-with-attributes/),

   ```
   <tag>
       <tag-name>currency</tag-name>
       <converter>
           <converter-id>defaultCurrencyConverter</converter-id>
       </converter>
   </tag>
   ```

   then you can ultimately use it as intented.

   ```
   <h:outputText value="10000000">
       <mycomp:currency />
   </h:outputText>
   ```

#### See also:

- [How to avoid repetitions / use constants in Facelets page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16919199/how-to-avoid-repetitions-use-constants-in-facelets-page/)
- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)

Comment: It's work. I still need to study more about JSF. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to ask questions not asked before :)